# Checkboxes checkout not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, css, checkbox

We have a clarion OSC but the boxes for create an account, ship to an other address and accept term & condition is not showing. This is the css for it:

```
.tm-hide { opacity: 0;/* filter:alpha(opacity=0);*/ }
.tm-checkbox {
    /*background: url('../../images/sprite.png') -3px -40px no-repeat;*/
    display:inline-block;
    width:17px;
    height:17px;vertical-align: middle;
}

.tm-radio { background: url('../../images/sprite.png') 0 -5px no-repeat;    display: inline;
    padding:0px;
    height:17px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
   }

.tm-checked { /*background-position:-75px -40px ;*/ }
.tm-selected { background-position: -73px -5px; }


.tm-checkbox-green {
    background: url('../../images/sprite.png') -3px -40px no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;

}
.tm-checked-green { background-position:-75px -40px ; }
.ie7 .tm-checkbox{ display:inline; }
```

I can not find what is going wrong, this is the url:

https://www.deli-discount.nl/dd_en/onestepcheckout/?___from_store=dd_nl

Can somebody please tell me what I am overlooking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those elements have the `tm-hide` class on them. Remove that class, and they'll display.

[image]

Comment: You are quick, do you know which file I need to adjust ?

Comment: It looks like it's added via javascript in this file: https://www.deli-discount.nl/js/megnor/megnor.min.js

Comment: Had to look what to do, found it. Thanks again